# Expected type after "as"

Tags: xcode, swift

Here is the code that is giving me trouble:

[image: Code]

I have tried taking away the !, adding ?, and adding semicolons. Nothing seems to be helping. Can someone please help me as to why it is giving me this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Don't put screenshots of code. Just copy and paste the code and hit the code format button.

Comment: Why is `vc` an optional (and `var`) although all assigned view controllers in the switch cases are non optionals?

Comment: No idea why you are getting that error without you pasting the code. That being said, you have `vc` as an optional and you forcable unwrap the assigned viewcontroller instead of letting it be an optional (makes no sense). Also, you don't need to use `break` in swift `switch` as long as you have a `case` body, swift doesn't support fallthrough.

Comment: Guess: It's a combination of two things. (1) You're using an older version of Xcode, from before Swift moved from `as` to `as!`, and (2) when you remove the `!`s, the compiler gives you a different error, as your view controllers probably inherit from `UIViewController`, not the `ViewController` class that's included in the standard template.